# how to load xml api data in mysql database using talend

Tags: etl, talend

> this is my xml structure

```
  <DataSet xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">    
    <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
        <NewDataSet xmlns="">
            <Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                <finyear>2019-20</finyear>
                <distCode>344</distCode>
                <blockCode>3276</blockCode>
                <DistrictName>ANUGUL </DistrictName>
                <BlockName>ANUGUL </BlockName>
                <target>24.00</target>
                <Applied>4</Applied>
                <totalvaw>1</totalvaw>
                <totalorsac>1</totalorsac>
                <totaldda>1</totaldda>
                <totaldc>1</totaldc>
            </Table>
        </NewDataSet>
    </diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

I have used these components

[image]

> this is mapping of tXmlMap
> [image]

I am not able to load data into mysql. Is there any problem in above components

Comment: Can you please ping url of the api?

Comment: @JimMacaulay  can i share it's structure here?

Comment: @JimMacaulay can i share here?